# Javascript Delay function but let loop wait for it

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know this is not a good idea to work with but every programmer wants to learn more.
For now I've been trying web scraping. First time creating the script and running it blocks my ip address. I was wrong because in my script i send too many request to the site, that way it will cost to much traffic to the site and make them to think that I'm an intruder,
I've come up to this idea to delay my request,How do i make my loop to wait for the function to finish? 
I don't want to use something like this. This will execute every 5 seconds

```
(function(links){ 
    setTimeout(function() { scrapeAnotherLink(links); }, delay); 
})(result[val]); 
 delay += 5000;
```

I want to wait for my ajax request to finish scrapping from the link provided then wait for 5 seconds then execute again.

my code.

scrape links. //just a sample

```
$('#scrape').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: 'scrape.php',  
          data:{Param:1},
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
              success: function(result) {  
                for(var val in result) { 
                  link = result[val];
                      scrapeAnotherLink(link);
                }
              },
          });
    });


function scrapeAnotherLink(link){
   //Some ajax here
    setTimeout(function() { 
      output_log(link);
   }, 5000);  
}

function output_log(str){

    $('#output').append(str+'<br/>');
}
```

I read that some scrappers pools ip address but i dont have an idea how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the job. Instead of using a loop make a recursive call that will be executed when the previous ajax request is over. The code below has some assumptions but it communicates the idea.

```
function executeAjax() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'scrape.php',  
        data:{Param:1},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(links) {  
            scrapeAnotherLink(links, 0);
        }
    });
}

function scrapeAnotherLink(links, index){
   //Some ajax here
    function executeCall(){
        $.ajax({
            url : links[index],
            success : function(str) {
               output_log(str);
               scrapeAnotherLink(links, ++index);
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(executeCall, 5000); 
}

function output_log(str){
    $('#output').append(str+'<br/>');
}
```

Comment: you forgot to stop the recursive call

Comment: True. It's just a `if(index >= links.length) return;`. Hope this helps